# How to fix my Prism region activation problem?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

Im setting up a completely new WPF Application where i use MVVM.
I'm using Prism 7.1.latest as Nuget in my Project.
After I passed my Login i will be forwarded to my MenuPage, where a User can choose between two different Options. Open Settings Page or an Upload Page.
The Menue is Static while I would only like to refresh the ContentView.

MenuPageViewModel.cs

```
public MenuPage2ViewModel(IContainerExtension container, IRegionManager regionManager)
        {
            _container = container;
            _regionManager = regionManager;

            _regionManager.Regions.Add("ContentRegion", new Region());

            this.CloseApplicationCommand = new DelegateCommand<Window>(this.CloseWindow);
            this.MinimizeApplicationCommand = new DelegateCommand<Window>(this.MinimizeWindow);
        }


        private DelegateCommand _loadSettingsPageCommand;

        public DelegateCommand LoadSettingsPageCommand => _loadSettingsPageCommand ?? (_loadSettingsPageCommand = new DelegateCommand(LoadSettingsPage, CanLoadSettingsPage));

        private void LoadSettingsPage()
        {
            IRegion region = _regionManager.Regions["ContentRegion"];

            var view = region.GetView(nameof(SettingsPage));
            if (view == null)
            {
                var t = _container.Resolve<SettingsPage>();
                region.Add(t, nameof(SettingsPage));
                view = region.GetView(nameof(SettingsPage));
            }

            region.Activate(view);
        }

        private bool CanLoadSettingsPage()
        {
            return true;
        }
```

MenuPage2.xaml the place my ContentControl should be loaded in

```xml
<Grid Column="2" Row="1">
           <ContentControl regions:RegionManager.RegionName="ContentRegion" />
</Grid>
```

SettingsPage.xaml my blue background view

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="TachiFox3Reader.Win.Views.SettingsPage"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mvvm="http://prismlibrary.com/"
             mvvm:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <Grid Background="Blue">

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

So when i click my button to activate Settings view nothing happens.
but there should be at least a blue background now in my grid where i definded the contentcontainer.

when i debug in VS then i can see the View contains my SettingsPage it is set toactive but my gui will show nothing.

Comment: Why can't you define the region from xaml and use `RequestNavigate` to load the settings page? I think your code can be drastically simplified.

Comment: I dont use `RequestNavigate` in my Project.  
It's my first time i do a WPF MVVM on my own.  
But thank you i will check this out.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line:

```
 _regionManager.Regions.Add("ContentRegion", new Region());
```

the region has already been added in the XAML.

The XAML that I use for holding the region is:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:wpfApp4="clr-namespace:WpfApp4"
        xmlns:regions="http://prismlibrary.com/"
        mc:Ignorable="d"        
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Command="{Binding LoadSettingsPageCommand}"></Button>
        <ContentControl regions:RegionManager.RegionName="ContentRegion" />
    </Grid>    
</Window>
```

Comment: when i remove this line, i get an error:  

`System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: 'The region manager does not contain the ContentRegion region.'`

Comment: This indicates the the regions is not been processed, it is declared in MenuPage2.xaml. Is this code <ContentControl regions:RegionManager.RegionName="ContentRegion" /> still there?

Comment: It's strang that you are still getting this error, I have updated the answer to show the XMAL that I used to hold the region